# List is not being appended right

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code block

```
purchase_amounts = []
item_price = ''
subtotal = 0
while item_price != 'done':
    item_price = input('Enter the amount to add to the list!')
    purchase_amounts.append(item_price)
    while purchase_amounts != [] and item_price != 'done':
        pop_var = purchase_amounts.pop()
        subtotal += int(pop_var)
print(purchase_amounts)
print(subtotal)
```

It runs as expected but for some reason the list purchase_amounts only shows done after it has been run.  I would like to know how to fix this and why it is not working for me at the moment.  The output I am getting is purchase_amounts = ['done'] and subtotal = 101 for 17, 17, 12, 55.  The expected output for purchase_amounts should be ['17','17','12','55']
-Thanks

Comment: Can you add the output you're getting and the output you're expecting?

Comment: Why are you using adding only strings to the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're appending is working fine, however you've added `done` to the list before you print it, and you're popping elements off the list while you are getting input. Therefore, you won't see those appended items in the final output

It's not clear what the purpose of popping is, so you can sum up the numbers after the loop instead

```
purchase_amounts = []
item_price = None 
while True:
    item_price = input('Enter the amount to add to the list!')
    if item_price == 'done':
        break 
    purchase_amounts.append(float(item_price))

print(purchase_amounts)
print(sum(purchase_amounts))
```

Comment: This code will throw an exception when `item_price` is not a number or `done`.

Answer (score 0):

`.pop()` will remove the item from the list. Try by getting the last item each time.

```
purchase_amounts[-1]
```

or even better add `item_price` to your list only when `item_price` is a number then use the function `sum()` to sum it.

```
purchase_amounts = []
item_price = ''
subtotal = 0
while item_price != 'done':
    item_price = input('Enter the amount to add to the list!')
    if item_price.isdigit():
        purchase_amounts.append(int(item_price)) 

subtotal = sum(purchase_amounts)
print(purchase_amounts)
print(subtotal)
```